# Intellij IDEA: How to add single class file to project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a very stupid question. Installing IDEA I want to create a very simple two files project (two java classes), one of which I already have. So I started empty project, created my new class file (I have only one top directory with this file) but I can't attach second to it. 
Earlier I used notepad and terminal for such simple porpuses and it was enough to copy file to "project" directory. Can someone explaine how can I link two class files in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Did you try right clicking the directory and saying new class?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't attach a second to it?"  Do you mean you can't add a second class?  Peter Lawrey's answer should fix that.  You can also add the file to the file system under the "src" directory and IDEA automatically read/update.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the `src` directory and select `New` -> `Java Class`

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't directory 'src' in my project. I moved both my files to src directory, they both compiled without errors but, however, in editor window, methods from my second class marked red, with pop-up message "Cannot resolve method .....". Guess it is some IDE issue, anyway with your help I compiled both files.)